# An error occurred while starting the application After using identity scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

i have this error

```
AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: BulkyBook.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository.IUnitOfWork Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: BulkyBook.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork': Unable to resolve service for type 'BulkyBook.DataAccess.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'BulkyBook.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork'.)
```

after using identity scafollding and i just change DbContext to IdentityDBContext and i tried everything and i have same error, and i didn't change anything else just my DbContext with the package

this my program.cs

```
using BulkyBook.DataAccess;
using BulkyBook.DataAccess.Repository;
using BulkyBook.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();;

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

and this is ApplicationDbContext

```
using BulkyBook.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace BulkyBook.DataAccess
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CoverType> CoverTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

i just want to fix this error to run my app again

Comment: If you revert back to your DbContext  name does the error still persist? In addition, did you tried to remove full migration snapshot and execute the migration command again?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make new project and choose individual accounts for authentication  [image: authentication]  by doing this it will configure the dbcontext by it self, after the project created scaffold the identity pages that you want to deal with and customise.

Comment: There any other solution without create new project?

Comment: it seems that the error came from the scoped service , try to put a break point on the scoped service and another break point to the repository that the applicationdbcontext injected in.